# Scrollable child and parent unscrollable

Tags: html, css

Lets say there is something like this:

```
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child">
 </div>
</div>
```

How to make `parent` to occupy the entire screen height?

And how to make `child` to be scrollable, if its height exceeds the parent height(which is screen max height).

I tried something like this:

```
.parent{
  height: 100vh;
 }

.child{
 overflow: auto;
 }
```

Comment: the `overflow` rule should go on the parent, not the child. When the child's content then overflows `100vh` a scroll bar would appear.

Comment: @zgood but i want the scroll bar to appear on child

Comment: Well then obviously you have to specify a height for the child, otherwise it has no reason to show scrollbars in the first place.

Comment: @Astacius the child needs a height then, or else what would you want it to overflow from? the overflow property goes hand-in-hand with the height

Comment: @zgood I wanted the parent to be 100vh, and child should fill all the available space and if there is not enough then it needs to be scrollable

Comment: @Astacius yes.. a scrollbar on the parent. because it has a height and its contents (`.child`) would be overflowing. Or give the child a height of 100vh and when its contents overflows it would get a scrollbar.

Answer (score 3):

Apply overflow rule to the parent div, see working example below:

```css
html, body {
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}
.parent {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.child span {
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  background: gray;
  padding: 10px
}

.child span:nth-child(odd) {
  background: lightgray
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child">
  <span>Child container 1</span>
  <span>Child container 2</span>
  <span>Child container 3</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of your CSS, try to apply this CSS:

```
html, body{
  overflow:hidden;
}
.parent{
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: scroll;
 }
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/thisisdg/t8wfqgje/3/) is the link to the fiddle supporting it.

```css
html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.parent {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">


    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit"Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    amet, consectetur adipisicing elit"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
    elit""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit""Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    consectetur adipisicing elit""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
    elit""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit""Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    consectetur adipisicing elit""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
    elit""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit" "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit""Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit"
  </div>
</div>
```